# Bind Sub-Grid before creating the record CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-4

i want to bind the sub grid of entity before creating the entity record i tried to fetchXml when on entity form load but it didn't work

Comment: The only way to do this may be a custom html web resource and JavaScript that pulls in the records from the other entity.

Comment: i tried to fetchXml when on pageload but it didn't work and i don't know the reason. please if you faced this problem before . can u  give me snapshot from code similar to this

Answer (score 4):

Subgrids are disabled before you create the record.

This because without the Id of the main record it's not possible to associate other records (with 1:N or N:N relationships)